# Getting object's instance variables from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a class that gets data from a plist file.

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *string;
}

@property (copy) NSString *string;

-(id)getData:(NSString *) a :(NSInteger) i;

@end
```

Here is the implementation.

```
@implementation myClass

-(id)getData:(NSString *) a :(NSInteger) i
{
    myClass *class = [[myClass alloc]init];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathToResource:a ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    class.string = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];

    return class;
}
```

My method `getData` has a string and an integer argument. This method is made to be placed inside of a for-loop so the `i` argument will be the for-loop index. Below is the method that it is meant to be inside of.

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        //this is a NSMutableArray that i created in the .h file this method is in
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {        
            [list addObject:[[[myClass alloc]init] getData: @"file" :i]];
        }

        //this is a NSTextField that i create in the .h file that this init method is in
        [instructions setStringValue:[list objectAtIndex:0].string];
    }

    return self;
}
```

What I want to do is set the string value of the instructions NSTextField to the `myClass.string` value that I stored in the list NSMutableArray. Is there a way to do this?

Every time I tried to do `[instructions setStringValue:[list objectAtIndex:0].string].`

When you store an object in a list, does it not carry over that object's instance variables or is there another way to access them?

Comment: try different syntax `[[list objectAtIndex:0] string]`

Comment: Your code is pretty garbled.  You are creating two instances of `myClass` for each one you insert.  And it's not clear to me that your `string` property will be properly retained.

Comment: Your code is not efficient, you're loading the same file over and over again. Just load it once!

Comment: I am quite new i will recode this once i get the functionality down. I am aware it could be done much more efficiently. Let me try bryan's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things which can be taken care over here:

1. class is a reserved keyword so don't use it as a local variable name whether it impacts your program or not.
2. you should make sure 'list' is a strong variable.

this statement should be

```
self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Use it like this: Also it should be referring using self

```
[self.instructions setStringValue:[[list objectAtIndex:0] string]];
```

Now coming to your problem: The instructions textfield seems to be IBOutlet and you are trying it to access in init method where it is always nil.

if you are in a windowController then setStringValue should go in windowDidLoad method.
if you are in a viewController then setStringValue should go in loadView.

Note: please call [super loadView] before setting the textfield value.
If it is a single file then better load it once rather then calling it in a for loop else you are good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I am extremely new to Objective-C and Cocoa.